# SQL Warning Code: -1100 SQLState 02000 no data error with Spring Boot JPA Data is not updated into DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

While saving data into MySQL database i am getting below SQL error.

SQL Warning Code: -1100 SQLState 02000 no data error with Spring Boot JPA Data is not updated into DB, Please find Below repository method and Bean Entity. SpringBoot version 2.2.5, Java Version 11, MySQL 5.5 version.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
public List<Status> resetStatus()
{
    logger.info("in resetStatus: reset the value null");
    String setBoxval = null;
    String setBoxId = null;
    List<Status> retRes = new ArrayList<Status>();
    Status s = new Status();
    try {
        entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE UserEntity ue SET ue.boxvalue = :boxVal, boxid = :boxId")
                     .setParameter("boxVal", setBoxval)
                     .setParameter("boxId", setBoxId)
                     .executeUpdate();
        s.setResponse("Success");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        s.setResponse("failue");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    retRes.add(s);
    return retRes;
}
```

Entity bean:

@Entity
@Table(name="tictacbox")
public class UserEntity 
    {

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="boxid")
    private Integer boxid;

    @Column(name="boxvalue")
    private String boxvalue;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getBoxid() {
        return boxid;
    }

    public void setBoxid(Integer boxid) {
        this.boxid = boxid;
    }

    public String getBoxvalue() {
        return boxvalue;
    }

    public void setBoxvalue(String boxvalue) {
        this.boxvalue = boxvalue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "userEntity [id=" + id + ", boxId=" + boxid + 
                ", boxvalue=" + boxvalue + "]";
    }
}
```

Log:

```
2020-04-03 11:25:45.937  INFO 18796 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-03 11:25:45.943  INFO 18796 --- [           main] com.test.TicTacToe.TicTacToeApplication  : Started TicTacToeApplication in 12.471 seconds (JVM running for 13.484)
2020-04-03 11:26:13.855  INFO 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-03 11:26:13.856  INFO 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-03 11:26:13.872  INFO 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 16 ms
2020-04-03 11:26:30.427  INFO 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.test.TicTacToe.user.HomeController   : resetStatus
2020-04-03 11:26:30.427  INFO 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.test.TicTacToe.user.UserService      : in service: resetStatus
2020-04-03 11:26:30.457  INFO 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.test.TicTacToe.user.UserService      : in resetStatus: reset the value null
2020-04-03 11:26:30.839  WARN 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: -1100, SQLState: 02000
2020-04-03 11:26:30.841  WARN 18796 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : no data
```

Comment: could you post the entity as well, is there any foreign key referenced somewhere? Also i would guess that we are referring to a MySQL ? Version ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev i have updated the request and added the Entity Bean.

Comment: in the createQuery() method could you change the table name as : tictacbox , or use the full qualified class name

Comment: Sorry no luck : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tictacbox is not mapped [UPDATE tictacbox ue SET ue.boxvalue = :boxVal, boxid = :boxId]

Comment: hmmm pretty odd, at least we clarified that the mapping isnt wrong. The same happens if you try to select the entities ? Is there any stored procedure attached to that table ?

Comment: no stored procedure used. My pom also having the dependency of Kafka too.